# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont

Tags: pdfbox, apache-tika, wildfly-10

I am using Apache Tika( tika-app 1.17) in wildfly modules.
While I start extracting PDF it always throws the error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont

For other file extensions it works fine.
Things I have tried out dependencies in apache-tika module.xml to PDFbox
Explicitly loaded org.apache.pdfbox from standalone.xml

I have also tried with the below structure
app1.war->(WEB-INF)lib-->app.jar->lib-->tika-app-1.17.jar

I have also jboss-deployment-structure.xml where

```
    <dependencies>
      <module name="com.company.tika" />         
    </dependencies>
```

is mentioned as a module dependency.
In MANIFEST.MF of the jar also, I have dependency to com.company.tika

Nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions or help would be thankful.

Thanks in Advance

Dwai

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could resolve the issue. The problem was the minor version of pdfbox, fontbox and jempbox were not the same. Hence the PDFFont was not initialized, because internally it needs to load the classes of fontbox also and probably there was a mismatch in the version id of the classes

Comment: This is weird, I thought tika-app is a "has everything" library, except maybe the things that don't have the proper license? Or were these PDFBox libraries in your classpath and thus confused everything?

Comment: Thanks @TilmanHausherr.
My understanding was also in line with yours and indeed it have everything.
So,I have removed other jars and tried also..It failed
Even it threw open-nlp noclassdeffound . I had to explicitly put that particular jar also. The problem does not happen in standalone but with wildfly

Answer (score 2):

setting SOLR_JAVA_STACK_SIZE='-Xss256M' only and not making any changes to libs solved this issue for me

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem.
Under linux i just install missing library pdfbox by:

```
apt-get install libpdfbox-java
and restart solr server
```

After this modification i need to change solr start parameter in ./bin/solr
from

```
SOLR_JAVA_STACK_SIZE='-Xss256kb'
```

to

```
SOLR_JAVA_STACK_SIZE='-Xss256M'
```

because i had error

> java.lang.StackOverflowErrorjava.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.StackOverflowError

of course i restart solr server again.

I hope, it help you reolve this problem.