# Solr indexing raises error while posting PDF

Tags: apache, solr

I am using Solr-6.6.4 version and Ubuntu 16 version.I have created a collection in Solr using the configuration files of the Solr example **techproducts**. I am trying to post a PDF in Solr but it is raising some errors.I have also installed the apache tika through maven. When I stop the Solr, Start it again and then post a PDF for the first time, it is giving me following error (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError)

```
SimplePostTool version 5.0.0
Posting files to [base] url http://localhost:8983/solr/ifarm/update...
Entering auto mode. File endings considered are xml,json,jsonl,csv,pdf,doc,docx,ppt,pptx,xls,xlsx,odt,odp,ods,ott,otp,ots,rtf,htm,html,txt,log
POSTing file Types.pdf (application/pdf) to [base]/extract
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #500 (Server Error) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/ifarm/update/extract?resource.name=%2Fhome%2Fubuntu%2Fpdf_cancer%2FTypes.pdf&literal.id=%2Fhome%2Fubuntu%2Fpdf_cancer%2FTypes.pdf
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/ifarm/update/extract. Reason:
<pre>    Server Error</pre></p><h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/jdk1.8.0_201/jre/lib/amd64/libawt_xawt.so: libXi.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1845)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
        at sun.java2d.cmm.lcms.LCMS$1.run(LCMS.java:209)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.java2d.cmm.lcms.LCMS.getModule(LCMS.java:203)
        at sun.java2d.cmm.lcms.LcmsServiceProvider.getModule(LcmsServiceProvider.java:34)
        at sun.java2d.cmm.CMMServiceProvider.getColorManagementModule(CMMServiceProvider.java:31)
        at sun.java2d.cmm.CMSManager.getModule(CMSManager.java:76)
        at java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace.toRGB(ICC_ColorSpace.java:177)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDDeviceRGB.init(PDDeviceRGB.java:69)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDDeviceRGB.toRGB(PDDeviceRGB.java:103)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.&lt;clinit&gt;(PDDocument.java:87)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:149)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:135)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.extraction.ExtractingDocumentLoader.load(ExtractingDocumentLoader.java:228)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:68)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:173)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2477)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:723)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:529)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:361)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:305)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
</pre>

</body>
</html>
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/ifarm/update/extract?resource.name=%2Fhome%2Fubuntu%2Fpdf_cancer%2FTypes.pdf&literal.id=%2Fhome%2Fubuntu%2Fpdf_cancer%2FTypes.pdf
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/ifarm/update...
Time spent: 0:00:00.795
```

And when I again post it (Second time), then it is giving the following error (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError)

```
SimplePostTool version 5.0.0
Posting files to [base] url http://localhost:8983/solr/ifarm_tech/update...
Entering auto mode. File endings considered are xml,json,jsonl,csv,pdf,doc,docx,ppt,pptx,xls,xlsx,odt,odp,ods,ott,otp,ots,rtf,htm,html,txt,log
POSTing file Types.pdf (application/pdf) to [base]/extract
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #500 (Server Error) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/ifarm_tech/update/extract?resource.name=%2Fhome%2Fubuntu%2Fpdf_cancer%2FTypes.pdf&literal.id=%2Fhome%2Fubuntu%2Fpdf_cancer%2FTypes.pdf
    SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Error 500 Server Error</title>
    </head>
    <body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
    <p>Problem accessing /solr/ifarm_tech/update/extract. Reason:
    <pre>    Server Error</pre></p><h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument
            at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:149)
            at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
            at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
            at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:135)
            at org.apache.solr.handler.extraction.ExtractingDocumentLoader.load(ExtractingDocumentLoader.java:228)
            at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:68)
            at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:173)
            at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2477)
            at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:723)
            at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:529)
            at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:361)
            at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:305)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    </pre>

    </body>
    </html>
    SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/ifarm_tech/update/extract?resource.name=%2Fhome%2Fubuntu%2Fpdf_cancer%2FTypes.pdf&literal.id=%2Fhome%2Fubuntu%2Fpdf_cancer%2FTypes.pdf
    1 files indexed.
    COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/ifarm_tech/update...
    Time spent: 0:00:00.354
```

Comment: looks like libs are missing under the path "...\solr-7.5.0\server\lib"...copy the required lib from "...\solr-7.5.0\contrib\extraction\lib"..example "pdfbox-2.0.9" and "pdfbox-tools-2.0.9"

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49271596/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-org-apache-pdfbox-pdm